# Symfony2 - embedded form not displaying

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have two entities, Kitchen and KitchenImage. Sub images for the Kitchens are stored in the KitchenImage entity.

The problem I am having is that file input box for the KitchenImage is not being displayed, however the label for it is?

**Twig File:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'role': 'form'}}) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.name, 'Title') }}
                {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter title' }}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    {{ form_label(form.image, 'Main Image') }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.image) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.image) }}
                    <p class="help-block">Main Image</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    {{ form_label(form.images, 'Sub Images') }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.images) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.images) }}
                    <p class="help-block">Sub Images</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.description) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.description) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.description, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace PWD\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use PWD\AdminBundle\Form\Type\KitchenType;
use PWD\AdminBundle\Form\Type\KitchenImageType;
use PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen;
use PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage;

class KitchenController extends Controller
{

    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $kitchen = new Kitchen();
        $form = $this->createForm(new KitchenType(), $kitchen);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            return "Yeah!";
        }

        return $this->render('PWDAdminBundle:Pages:add-kitchen.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**KitchenType**

```
<?php

namespace PWD\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class KitchenType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('description', 'textarea')
                ->add('image', 'file')
                ->add('images', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new KitchenImageType(),
                    'cascade_validation' => true,
                    ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'kitchen';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

**KitchenImageType**

```
<?php 

namespace PWD\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class KitchenImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image', 'file');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'allow_add'    => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'kitchenimage';
    }
}
```

**KitchenImage Entity**

```
<?php

namespace PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * KitchenImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="kitchen_image")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class KitchenImage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     minWidth = 800,
     *     maxWidth = 800,
     *     minHeight = 467,
     *     maxHeight = 467
     * )
     */
    public $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kitchen", inversedBy="image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kitchen_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $kitchen;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setImage(UploadedFile $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set kitchen
     *
     * @param \PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen $kitchen
     * @return KitchenImage
     */
    public function setKitchen(\PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen $kitchen = null)
    {
        $this->kitchen = $kitchen;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kitchen
     *
     * @return \PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Kitchen 
     */
    public function getKitchen()
    {
        return $this->kitchen;
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/our-work';
    }

    public function upload()
    {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getImage()) {
        return;
    }

    // use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getImage()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getImage()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getImage()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->image = null;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return KitchenImage
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
}
```

**Kitchen Entity**

```
<?php 

namespace PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="kitchen")
 */
class Kitchen
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     minWidth = 800,
     *     maxWidth = 800,
     *     minHeight = 467,
     *     maxHeight = 467
     * )
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="KitchenImage", mappedBy="kitchen")
     * @Assert\Type(type="PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage")
     */
    protected $images;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $imagePath;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Kitchen
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Kitchen
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $image
     * @return Kitchen
     */
    public function setImage(UploadedFile $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Add images
     *
     * @param \PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage $images
     * @return Kitchen
     */
    public function addImage(\PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage $images)
    {
        $this->images[] = $images;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove images
     *
     * @param \PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage $images
     */
    public function removeImage(\PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage $images)
    {
        $this->images->removeElement($images);
    }

    /**
     * Get images
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Get absolute path
     */
    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->imagePath
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->imagePath;
    }

    /**
     * Get web path
     */
    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->imagePath;
    }

    /**
     * Get upload root directory
     */
    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    /**
     * Get upload directory
     */
    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        return 'uploads/our-work';
    }

    /**
     * Upload image
     */
    public function upload()
    {
    // The file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getImage()) {
        return;
    }

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getImage()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getImage()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->imagePath = $this->getImage()->getClientOriginalName();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->image = null;
    }

    /**
     * Set imagePath
     *
     * @param string $imagePath
     * @return Kitchen
     */
    public function setImagePath($imagePath)
    {
        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imagePath
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImagePath()
    {
        return $this->imagePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by making a new twig template with just: {{ form(form) }} in it.  Won't look pretty but see if shows the input box.  That will isolate the problem to either the code or the template.

Comment: @Cerad Hi - same problem occurs - no file input for images is displayed.

Comment: Ok.  I'm assuming the kitchen image input box is showing up?.  Do you actually have kitchemImages attached to kitchen?  In any event, have your controller just make a KitchenImageFormType and feed it to the {{ form(form) }} template.  Make sure nothing else is in the template.  Just want to see the form.  This will isolate the problem to either the KitcheImage itself or to some sort of collection issue.  It's a bit strange that KitchenImage has public properties and that some of them are not mapped to the database.

Comment: @Cerad File input comes up fine when making a form with the KitchenImageForm Type.

Comment: Ok.  Am I correct in assuming that the Kitchen entity that you are testing against does not have any KitchemImages yet?  I suspect you might have a problem with the allow_add stuff.  In your controller, add a kitchenImage to your kitchen and then see what happens.

Comment: @Cerad The Kitchen entity does not have KitchenImages yet. I'm not sure how I would go about that. KitchenImages images are added to the Kitchen by the method KitchenImages->setKitchen()

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you have `allow_add` in your KitchenImageType when it should be on the collection in your KitchenType

```
class KitchenType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->add('image', 'file')
            ->add('images', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new KitchenImageType(),
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'allow_add' => true, // *** Need this here, remove it from KitchenImageType
                ));
}
```

There could be other problems but I think that's it.  You might want to go through the example in the book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html very carefully.  There are quite a few things needed to get the New stuff to work.

==================================

And to respond the the comment about adding a kitchen image for testing, just

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $kitchen = new Kitchen();
    $kitchen->addImage(new KitchenImage());
    $form = $this->createForm(new KitchenType(), $kitchen);
```

It's a bit confusing both image and images properties.  Later on you might want to rename images to something like subImages and image to mainImage just for clarity.  But it still should work.

==================================

And it your kitchen entity you will need this so things persist properly:

```
// Note that your are only passing one image at a time to argument is $image not $images
public function addImage(\PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage $kitchenImage)
{
    $this->images[] = $kitchenImage;
    $kitchenImage->setKitchen($this);  // *** Need this for persisting
    return $this;
}
```

=========================================

It's always kind of fun when you go through a trouble shooting process only to realize that the basic problem was something completely different.  You need to read up on how file uploading works, not just in Symfony/Doctrine but on the web in general.

With a new project, carefully read through and implement this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

Once you understand how to upload files (i.e. images) and how to store them (path in database, the file itself somewhere on the web server) then you can go back to your kitchen stuff and handle images properly.  Once you do, just get your main kitchen image working then add in a collection of sub images.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far by the way. I did the changes suggested but  no difference.

Comment: Added the extra bit of code. I get a strange result - the input box comes up but there's two labels and a 0 printed - http://i.imgur.com/YpO4szi.png

Comment: Have I set up the relationships incorrectly? It was quite confusing as this is my first time using Doctrine - made more difficult because of two file inputs. Would it be better to just start again?

Comment: Yep on starting over.  You are trying to learn one of the more complicated work flows.  I would suggest leaving what you have, make a brand new Symfony 2.3 project and then actually implement the example in the manual:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.  It will take some time but at then end of it I think you will have a much better understanding of Doctrine and collections.  Plus, you will have a stand alone application that you can refer back to.

Comment: @Cared - added in last bit of code but left with the same issue.

Comment: I should point out the Doctrine relations are irrelevant at this point.  Did you add a KitchenImage to your Kitchen in your controller and pass the form to the test template?  I really would have expected that to work.

Comment: @Cered - Yeah I did (http://pastebin.com/8vJrKkm5) but it produces this - http://i.imgur.com/YpO4szi.png

Comment: Wait a second.  You got the Choose File button?  What else did you expect?  On chrome that's all you going to get.  Try picking a file and see what happens.  And look at it under FireFox as well.

Comment: @Cared - I was wondering why it was printing two labels and a random 0? However when I submit I get the following error - This value should be of type PWD\WebsiteBundle\Entity\KitchenImage.

Comment: Updated my answer.  If you do have problems getting file uploads to work then I'd suggest starting a new question focusing on just that.